# The map $f(z)=\frac{z-2}{z+3}$ rotates $z$ some angle $\theta$ radians about some point $P$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $H=\{z\in \mathbb C~:~\operatorname{Im(z)>0}\}$, Consider the function $f:H\rightarrow H$ defined by $$f(z)=\frac{z-2}{z+3}$$
Then prove that $f$ rotates $z$ some angle $\theta$ radians about some point $P$.

How to say that $f(z)=\frac{z-2}{z+3}=e^{i\theta}(z-P)$?
Is it helpful the fact $\frac{z-2}{z+3}=1-\frac{5}{z+3}$?

Comment: No, you have to show that $f(z) - P=e^{i\theta}(z-P)$ for some $P$ and some $\theta$. A good start would be to determine the fixed points of $f$.

Comment: @MartinR $e^{i \theta} (z - P) + P$ is a rotation of $\mathbb C$, clearly $f$ isn't a rotation in that sense. We're required to show that $f$ is a rotation of the Poincare upper half-plane, that is, $f = g \circ h \circ g^{-1}$, where $h(z) = e^{i \phi} z$ and $g$ maps $\mathbb D$ to $\mathbb H$. A non-parabolic transformation has the form $\tilde g \circ \tilde h \circ \tilde g^{-1}$, where $\tilde g^{-1}(z) = (z - z_1)/(z - z_2)$, $\tilde h(z) = k z$, $k = f'(z_1)$ and $z_{1, 2}$ are the fixed points of $f$. We need to verify that $z_2 = \overline {z_1}$ and that $|f'(z_1)| = 1$.